# Interference between \onslide and \setbeamercovered{transparent}

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

I'm trying to use `\onslide` in a table, but since I have the option `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` in the preamble, it does not produce the overlay of columns.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test 1}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> A
        \item<2-> B
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test 2}
    \begin{table} \caption{Test}
        \begin{tabular}{lc<{\onslide<2->}c<{\onslide}}
             A & 1 & 2 \\
             B & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I comment the second line it works, otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `\onslide+`:

```
    \begin{tabular}{lc<{\onslide+<2->}c<{\onslide}}
```

and by the way, arguments for `xcolor` must be in parentheses:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
```