# How do I dim the text in certain columns of a table (beamer)?

Tags: tables, beamer, transparency, hf-tikz

I want to dim (ie, make transparent) certain selected columns of a table when on a slide, so that I can highlight the remaining columns without explicitly drawing attention to them by using colour. Currently I am trying to use the `hf-tikz` package and `opacity` option, but somehow I don't see any effect. I used colours to check if the command is actually working -- and it is -- so the issue is that without colour, plain dimming of text seems to have no visible effect. How do I improve this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\usepackage{nccmath} 
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=red,colback=white, width=\textwidth, left=0pt}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=red, colback=white}    
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}


\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Warmup}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}%

  \only<1>{\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox, left = 0.1 mm, right=0.1 mm, top = 0.4mm, bottom = 0.4mm, hide=<2->]
Simpler case: blsadf asdf;laskjdf;laksdf;la
\end{tcolorbox}}
\pause 

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c}
%    \begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1>}c<{\onslide} c c c c c c c}
    \toprule
$a$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$d$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$e$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$g$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$h$}\\
\midrule
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\mu$ & $\epsilon$\\
        $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\mu$ & $\epsilon$\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Notation}
    \label{TableNotation}
\end{table} 
%
\pause

    \begin{mylemmma}{Our lemma}{lem}
        We have the following bound: 
        \[f(x) \leq g(x) + r(x) + m(x)\]
    \end{mylemmma}

    \pause
    \begin{tcolorbox}[hbox, left = 0.1 mm, right=0.1 mm, top = 0.4mm, bottom = 0.4mm]
Main Idea: $x$ is small enough for Taylor approximation. 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see it puts the stuff on the background, which is why you cannot see the shading. (Also remove the space in `\tikzmarkin<2->[colhl]{c1} $a$`.) You could just use the `tikzmarknode` library instead.

Comment: The ```tikzmark``` library seems to be more for things like adding annotations at specific symbols. I do not see a command in the manual that lets me do both 1) connect all elements of a column together, and 2) make them transparent. Was there a specific command using ```tikzmarknode``` that you had in mind? Thank you!

Comment: I think you can use e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341184/194703. The author indicates where you can find her. One may also train `collcell` to uncover table columns. I would be surprised if no one had done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use beamer tools, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113040/194703).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         

%\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

  \setbeamercovered{transparent}%

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within \linewidth horizontally

    \begin{tabular}{>{\onslide<1>}c<{\onslide} c c c c c c c}
    \toprule
$a$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$d$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$e$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f$}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$g$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$h$}\\
\midrule
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\mu$ & $\epsilon$\\
        $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ & $\mu$ & $\epsilon$\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}

    \caption{Notation}
    \label{TableNotation}
\end{table} 
\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Off-topic: personally I would not resize the table.)

Comment: Hm, so when I combined this code with other stuff on my slide, it messed up the other transparencies somehow :(

Comment: @lazulikid Do you load `\usepackage{array}`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I need it to write optimization problems nicely aligned columnwise in different rows.

Comment: @lazulikid It is very hard for me hard for me to debug this. Can you post the code that causes the problems? (One may also think of employing `collcell`.)

Comment: Thank you! I edited the original question with the complete code for the slide. There are two lines in it with comments. If you uncomment them and comment out the line ```\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c} ```, you can see the difference in output. While I don't mind the transparencies created by ```\setbeamercovered{transparent}```,  the problem is these transparencies are a bit inconsistent (for example, the table caption and text of the ```tcolorbox``` at the bottom of the slide aren't made transparent, so it looks very odd (it looks like an oversight...)

Comment: @lazulikid You can control the opacity with commands like `\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}`, where `30` can be replaced by any value between `0` (invisible) and `100` (fully visible). Likewise, the visibility of `tcolorbox` can be arranged with the `beamer hidden` style. I think you only need to synchronize the opacities to get what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108562/discussion-between-lazulikid-and-schrodingers-cat).